# Choosing threshold values in Harris Corner Detection Algorithm

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, edge-detection

[image: Harris]
Above is a representation of calculating corners in an image using Harris Corner Detection Algorithm . I have implemented up to step 5 , however , in step 6 , I can not decide how to set up the threshold for the values obtained in calculating `R = det(H) - k(trace(H))^2` .
This screenshot has been taken from Robert Collins slides http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rcollins/CSE486/lecture06.pdf , where he mentions of taking corners
and setting up threshold values of `-1000 for edges and 10000 for corners` . Values in between doesn't have any significance .

My question is he was subjective about his experiment and his choice of sample image , and for a particular image , values of `-10000 and 10000` worked . In real life , there would be no way of knowing what sort of image to expect , how would then the threshold value be chosen .

P.S: I have tried with Matlab's `rice.png` , the threshold values are way off .

Edit: I have looked at this question about Harris Corner  [Implementing a Harris corner detector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862225/implementing-a-harris-corner-detector)
which says " Just collect all pixels that have a higher value than all other pixels in the 5x5 neighborhood around them". I want something more mathematical for to implement .

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

More mathematical? OK, how about "Locate all local maxima of the filtered image, then pick the highest N", which is what the responder in that question is recommending. As for N, use whatever prior information you have about the scene. For example, are you interested in a checkerboard with 100 corners? Then set N=200 to make sure you get most of them.

BTW, a handy way to do that is to look for unchanged values in the filtered image and a dilated version of it, the dilation being done with a 5x5 flat structuring element.

Comment: Dilation will enable me to pick the highest , it won't enable to put the values in certain ranges , if I am correctly interpreting what you are saying . BTW: Is there any note / article of this dilation technique , would be great to follow, if so.

Comment: Not sure what "range" you are talking about. AFAIK there is no general way to define a lower threshold for the "cornerness" measure provided by the Harris filter. It's just a score, and the higher it is, the more "spiky" or "point-like" the image looks around a certain pixel. You need to add your priors to decide which score values are good enough. The dilation trick? It's one of those things rediscovered over and over. An image I and its dilated version D are equal only at the local maxima of I. Write down the equations defining the dilation to convince yourself that this is the case.

Comment: The "range" , you know <a - edge , >a and <b - (garbage) ; >b corners -- I want to leave out the garbage portion .

Comment: What is "garbage"? Answer the question, get your threshold.

Comment: Okay , sorry no offence , garbage means the pixels that are neither edges nor corners . I am getting the thresholds , just wait .

Answer (score 1):

As the Harris R value, in the surroundings of a corner, increase in a polynomial way (as a function of the window's size), I use this little "trick" to find a 'global' threshold value for the corners:

```
thresh = n² * 100;
```

The variable *n* represents the area of the Harris window. The value 100 is experimental...but it works if the image is equalized.

Then, it is necessary to apply a non-maximal suppression and the threshold value:

```
dilateR = imdilate(R, ones[3 3]);
RESULT = dilateR == R & R > thresh; % non-maximal suppression and thresholding
```

Rice image and Harris corners using several windows size:

[image: Rice image and Harris corners using several windows size]