# When implementing a Harris Corner detector, where are the window shifts taken into account?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, corner-detection

I was looking at how to implement a Harris Corner detector in MATLAB, and in various online lecture slides, it details the process as follows:
[image]

However, as I'm understanding it right now, the first couple of steps in this process are for calculating the second moment matrix M. **However, as described in the picture below, there are also vectors involving u and v, which are the window being shifted. Where is that being taken into account in the code** (for example, in the code shown in the answers here: [Implementing a Harris corner detector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862225/implementing-a-harris-corner-detector))

[image]

I think I'm just misunderstanding something in how the math translates over to the code here. Also, the pictures of the slides above were taken from here: http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~maov/classes/comp_photo_vision08f/lect/18_feature_detectors.pdf

Comment: This question is off-topic for SO. Try SP.

Comment: @FrancescoCallari Will do for next time, thanks! I wasn't sure which to go, since my question was a mix of coding vs image processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That description is incomplete and inaccurate.

When in doubt, always go to the source. In this case, the paper by Harris and Stephens:

> C. Harris and M. Stephens (1988). "A combined corner and edge detector" (PDF). Proceedings of the 4th Alvey Vision Conference. pp. 147–151.
>   http://www.bmva.org/bmvc/1988/avc-88-023.pdf

(link taken from [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection#The_Harris_&_Stephens_/_Plessey_/_Shi%E2%80%93Tomasi_corner_detection_algorithms)).

If you read the paper, you'll see that they indeed write

> E(x,y) = (x,y)M(x,y)<sup>T</sup>

But you can read the rest of the text on the page that contains that equation to learn that E(x,y) is the change in intensities produced by a small shift (x,y). One eigenvector of M now gives the direction of maximal change, and the eigenvalues of M indicate how strong this change is in that direction and perpendicular to it. (x,y) is no longer relevant, we don't care about any specific shift distances, we just care about how much the signal will change given a small shift in any chosen direction.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So because we're able to get all the information we need off of just the matrix M, we don't need to manually implement shifts.

Comment: @Yuerno: Indeed. I the paper, the authors base their work off a previous corner detector, and they say "The response [of the other filter] is anisotropic because only a discrete set of shifts at every 45 degrees is considered - all possible small shifts can be covered by performing an analytic expansion about the shift origin". The matrix M gives you this isotropic information.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! Thanks for linking the paper as well, definitely going to go over it.