# How to apply the non-maximum suppression for the corner detection

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, filtering

Finally I have a working code which detects the corner of the rectangles in an image.But the problem is the code is detecting multiple points at same corner. Now I am trying to introduce non-maximum suppression in my code but it was not working. I have tried one suggestion previous times but it is also not working. how to carry this non-maximum suppression properly.

[image: OD6.jpg]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import matplotlib.image as im   
from scipy import ndimage


# 1. Before doing any operations convert the image into gray scale image

img = im.imread('OD6.jpg')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

# split
R=img[:,:,0]
G=img[:,:,1]
B=img[:,:,2]


M,N=R.shape

gray_img=np.zeros((M,N), dtype=int);

for i in range(M):                     
        for j in range(N):
            gray_img[i, j]=(R[i, j]*0.2989)+(G[i, j]*0.5870)+(B[i, j]*0.114);

plt.imshow(gray_img, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

# 2. Applying sobel filter to find the gradients in x and y direction respectively and remove noise
# using gaussian filter with sigma=1 

imarr = np.asarray(gray_img, dtype=np.float64)
ix = ndimage.sobel(imarr, 0)
iy = ndimage.sobel(imarr, 1)
ix2 = ix * ix
iy2 = iy * iy
ixy = ix * iy
ix2 = ndimage.gaussian_filter(ix2, sigma=1)
iy2 = ndimage.gaussian_filter(iy2, sigma=1)
ixy = ndimage.gaussian_filter(ixy, sigma=1)
c, l = imarr.shape
result = np.zeros((c, l))
r = np.zeros((c, l))

rmax = 0 # initialize the maximum value of harris response
for i in range(c):
        for j in range(l):
            m = np.array([[ix2[i, j], ixy[i, j]], [ixy[i, j], iy2[i, j]]], dtype=np.float64)
            r[i, j] = np.linalg.det(m) - 0.04 * (np.power(np.trace(m), 2))
            if r[i, j] > rmax:
                rmax = r[i, j]

# 3. Applying non maximum supression
for i in range(c - 1):
        for j in range(l - 1):
            if r[i, j] > 0.01 * rmax and r[i, j] > r[i-1, j-1] and r[i, j] > r[i-1, j+1]\
                                     and r[i, j] > r[i+1, j-1] and r[i, j] > r[i+1, j+1]:
                result[i, j] = 1


xy_coords = np.flip(np.column_stack(np.where(result==1)), axis=1)
print (xy_coords)

pc, pr = np.where(result == 1)
plt.plot(pr, pc, "b.")  
plt.imshow(img, 'gray')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of materials available on Corner Detection. This is also solved in StackOverflow, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862225/implementing-a-harris-corner-detector).

Comment: Goswami I have see all those one. In fact I have take a part of the code from one of the answeres but it is not working.