# Can't find the right corners of an image

Tags: python, visual-studio, image-processing

- I need to find the 4 corners of the front of the box.
- I tried putting different variables (number of corners, quality level etc.) but it only managed to find 1 correct corner.
- Here is my code so far:

[image]

and this is the output:

[image]

Comment: look for the harris-corner-detector method, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862225/implementing-a-harris-corner-detector/43837296#43837296

Comment: Please do not use images of the code, always insert it as text with proper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to find the corners using other image processing techniques. As your image is full of details, we can use thresholds, eroding and dilations. Take a look below:

```
color = cv2.imread('box.png')
plt.imshow(color);
plt.xticks([]);
plt.yticks([]);
```

[image]

```
gray = cv2.imread('box.png',0)
gray[gray > 10 ] = 255
plt.imshow(gray,cmap='gray');
plt.xticks([]);
plt.yticks([]);
```

[image]

```
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
gray = cv2.dilate(gray,kernel,iterations = 10)
gray = cv2.erode(gray,kernel,iterations=15)
gray = cv2.dilate(gray,kernel,iterations = 3)
plt.imshow(gray,cmap='gray');
plt.xticks([]);
plt.yticks([]);
```

[image]

```
y,x = np.where(gray == 255)
y_index = np.argmin(y)
x_coord = x[y_index]
gray[0:,0:x_coord] = 0
plt.imshow(gray,cmap='gray');
plt.xticks([]);
plt.yticks([]);
```

[image]

```
# Top-left
top_left = (x_coord,y[y_index])
cv2.circle(color,top_left,5,[0,255,0],-1);

# Bottom-left
y,x = np.where(gray == 255)
y_index = np.argmax(y)
x_coord = x[y_index]
bottom_left = (x_coord,y[y_index])
cv2.circle(color,bottom_left,5,[0,255,0],-1);

# Top-right
y,x = np.where(gray == 255)
x_index = np.argmax(x)
y_coord = y[x_index]
top_right = (x[x_index],y_coord)
cv2.circle(color,top_right,5,[0,255,0],-1);

# Bottom-right
for y in range(top_right[1],gray.shape[0],1):
    roi = gray[y:y+1,top_right[0]-11:top_right[0]]
    if np.all((roi == 0)):
        break
bottom_right = (top_right[0],y)
cv2.circle(color,bottom_right,5,[0,255,0],-1);
plt.imshow(color);
plt.xticks([]);
plt.yticks([]);
```

[image]

You can play with all values to get different results. You may need to change the code a bit if you change the perspective.

Answer (score 0):

A corner detector will not work. They never work.

Look for the farthest non-black points in the N, NE, SE and S directions.